# date.parse not sure how to implement

Tags: javascript

I am looking for some date.parse() help for JavaScript.  I have been searching different forums and sites and still have not been able to find a decent example of how to implement this.  I am taking a beginning web design class and my instructor has asked for me to do this : "Set the placeholder text for the text box to “Enter a date.” Add an empty paragraph tag set to the document. In a separate JavaScript file code the event handler for the button to set the paragraph text to state whether or not the entered value is a recognizable date format. The Date.parse() method will return a number if passed a valid date string and the special value NaN (not a number) otherwise. NaN can be check for using the built-in function isNaN(). (You may want to refer to your online resources for more information on the Date object, NaN , and isNaN().)"  I have been to a ton of websites that show the string but I need a dumbed down example of how to actually use it. here is my html code for the button:

```
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="dateTextInput" size="40" placeholder="Please Enter A Date">
<input type="button" id="addButton" value="Enter a Date">
</form>
<p></p>
</body>
```

and here is what I have for my .js file:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}

function handleButtonClick() {
var textInput = document.getElementById("addDateButton");
var dateString = textInput.value;

if (dateString == "") {
alert("Please enter a date");
}
else {
```

my issue is after my else, if that is even appropriate.  I am lost as how to implement the date.parse function.  I know it's date.parse(variable) but not sure how to make sure it can be a valid format.  Dates can be entered in numerous ways.  Should I make an array of possible dates and validate it that way? Or is there a simpler option?  A link to a great guide would also be helpful, if an answer cannot be provided here.  Thank you for your time.

Update;  here is what I am using now.  It halfway works.  It alerts for an empty set.  I just can't get the parse to alert:

```
function handleButtonClick() {
var textInput = document.getElementById("dateTextInput");
var dateString = textInput.value;
var dateValue = Date.parse(dateString);
var valid = !isNaN(dateValue);

if (dateString == "") {
    alert("Please enter a date");

} else {
  return(valid);
}
}
```

Comment: It’s `Date.parse` (JS is case-sensitive), and you have been told already what calling this method will return – so where is the actual problem?

Comment: Thank you for the case reminder.  The problem is that I am not sure how to put in the Date.parse.  I am guessing it could be else {  Date.parse(dateString).

Answer (score 0):

I hope everthing is understandable.

```
<form id="dateForm">
    <!-- pattern just allow such format X.X.XXXX Or XX.XX.XXXX Or X.XX.XXXX Or XX.X.XXXX -->

    <input type="text" id="dateTextInput" size="40" pattern="^\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4,4}$" placeholder="Please Enter A Date">
    <input type="submit" id="addButton" value="Enter a Date">
</form>


<script>
// onsubmit ist just called when dateTextInput is empty or has got valid date
document.getElementById('dateForm').onsubmit = function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to reload page
    var date = document.getElementById('dateTextInput').value;

    if(date === ''){ // always use === because == is sometimes buggy
      alert('Please enter a date');
    }
    else{
      var convertedDate = date.split('.'); // -> ['03','06','1985']
      convertedDate = new Date(convertedDate[2],convertedDate[1],convertedDate[0]);
      console.log(convertedDate.getTime()); // I think you wanted to get Milliseconds, but this works just as well
    }

    return false;

};
</script>
```

When the order of the day, month and year is not right, then just edit the pattern of the input-field and this codeline:

```
convertedDate = new Date(convertedDate[2],convertedDate[1],convertedDate[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Dates can be entered in numerous ways. Should I make an array of possible dates and validate it that way?

No array. You should just accept what `Date.parse` does accept:

> whether the entered value is a recognizable date format. The `Date.parse()` method will return a number if passed a valid date string and NaN otherwise.

"*recognizable*" does refer to `Date.parse` capatibilites I'd say. It's trivial to implement then:

```
var dateValue = Date.parse(dateString);
var valid = !isNaN(dateValue);

// grab the paragraph
if (valid)
   // set the paragraph text accordingly
else
   // output something different
```

Comment: You spelled it out and I still cannot get it to function, I have updated my code.  What am I doing wrong.  Will it not work as a local file.  Or am I just a dumbass?

Comment: You're `return`ing the boolean `valid` from your function. Aren't you supposed to output it?